# Strange character docker exec

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, docker, docker-exec

I'm trying to create a script to run a docker cluster.

In my script there is a moment that I want to copy some files from the docker to my local machine. So I'm creating the `CONTAINER_WORKDIR` variable.

```
CONTAINER_WORKDIR=`docker exec -it jmeter-master /bin/pwd`
```

The value stored in `CONTAINER_WORKDIR` is:

```
/usr/local/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin
```

The problem is that there is a strange character in the end of this variable. Try to execute the line below:

```
echo "docker cp jmeter-master:$CONTAINER_WORKDIR/output.csv ."
```

My expected result is

```
docker cp jmeter-master:/usr/local/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/output.csv .
```

But the real output is:

```
/output.csv .ter-master:/usr/local/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin
```

The `pwd` or the `docker exec` command is returning a returning character.

There is a way to remove this character from `CONTAINER_WORKDIR` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script that executes what I presume must be

```
CONTAINER_WORKDIR=$(docker exec -it jmeter-master /bin/pwd)
```

may have been written with an editor that stores text files with DOS line-endings (like Notepad++).

Run `dos2unix` on that script, or use

```
$ tr -d '\r' <script >script-new
```

to fix it.